# React props of parent are not passed to child component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm passing props to a child component, from a parent component that receive this same prop from his own parent.

For some reason, when the parent props get updated, this update does not affect the child component.

The component in itself is very basic:

here's the parent :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { Icon } from 'antd'

import BaseProductSelector from '../BaseProductSelector'
import BaseProductPreview from '../BaseProductPreview'
import FullDesignSelector from '../FullDesignSelector'
import ColorPicker from '../ColorPicker'
import GeneratorProgress from '../GeneratorProgress'
import GeneratorError from '../GeneratorError'
import BPDetails from './BPDetails'

const GeneratorFlow = styled.div`
  /*background-color: #eeeeee;*/
  padding: 0 60px;
  h3 {
    color: #444;
  }
  .innerGenFlow {
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 40px -14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  }
`

export default class ProductGeneratorFlow extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super()

    let colors
    if (props.product) {
      colors = props.product.variations.filter(p => p.type === 'color')
    } else {
      colors = []
      // colors.push(props.baseProduct.variations.filter(p => p.type === 'color')[0])
    }

    this.state = {
      pickedColors: colors,
      done: false,
      error: false,
    }
    this.setStep = this.setStep.bind(this)
    this.setKey = this.setKey.bind(this)
    this.showBP = this.showBP.bind(this)
    this.hideBP = this.hideBP.bind(this)
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
    this.toggleColor = this.toggleColor.bind(this)
    this.toggleAll = this.toggleAll.bind(this)
    this.productCreated = this.productCreated.bind(this)
    this.productPending = this.productPending.bind(this)
    this.setFirstColor = this.setFirstColor.bind(this)
    this.displayError = this.displayError.bind(this)
  }

  setStep(step) {
    this.setState({ step })
  }

  showBP() {
    this.setState({ BPDisplayed: true })
  }

  hideBP() {
    this.setState({ BPDisplayed: false })
  }

  getBaseProd() {
    const bpid = this.props.product.supplierBaseProductId
    const result = this.props.base_products.filter(obj => obj._id === bpid)
    return result[0]
  }

  setKey(activeKey) {
    this.setState({
      activeKey,
    })
  }

  onChange(activeKey) {
    this.setState({
      activeKey,
    })
  }

  productPending() {
    this.setState({
      done: false,
      error: false,
    })
    this.props.showBP()
  }

  productCreated() {
    this.props.displaySuccess()
    this.setState({ done: true })
  }

  displayError() {
    this.setState({ error: true })
  }

  toggleColor(color) {
    let pickedColors = this.state.pickedColors
    if (this.state.pickedColors.includes(color)) {
      // console.log(pickedColors.filter(i => i != color).length)
      pickedColors = pickedColors.filter(i => i != color)
    } else {
      pickedColors.push(color)
    }
    this.setState({
      pickedColors,
    })
  }

  test(id) {
    this.setState({picked: true})
    this.props.select(id)
  }

  toggleAll(value) {
    if (value === true) {
      this.setState({
        pickedColors: this.props.baseProduct.variations.filter(p => p.type === 'color'),
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({ pickedColors: [] })
    }
  }

  setFirstColor() {
    if (this.state.pickedColors.length > 0) {
      this.props.setVariation(this.state.pickedColors[0])
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.error) {
      return (
        <GeneratorError
          showBP={this.props.showBP}
          reset={this.productPending}
        />
      )
    }
    if (this.state.done) {
      return (
        <GeneratorProgress
          active
          showBP={this.props.showBP}
          reset={this.productPending}
        />
      )
    }
    if (this.props.product) {
      return (
        <GeneratorFlow>
          <FullDesignSelector
            designs={this.props.designs}
            select={this.test}
            addedDesigns={this.props.addedDesigns}
            getImage={this.props.getImage}
            removeDesign={this.props.removeDesign}
            active
            printingZone={this.props.printingZone}
            setStep={this.setStep}
            showBP={this.showBP}
            showDS={this.props.showDS}
            setKey={this.setKey}
          />
          <ColorPicker
            baseProduct={this.props.baseProduct}
            product={this.props.product}
            picked={this.state.pickedColors}
            toggleColor={this.toggleColor}
            variation={this.props.variation}
            selectAll={this.toggleAll}
            toggleFirstColor={this.props.toggleFirstColor}
            setVariation={this.props.setVariation}
            selectedColor={
              this.props.variation ? this.props.variation.value : null
            }
            setPreviewColor={this.props.setVariation}
          />
          <BaseProductPreview
            addedDesigns={this.props.addedDesigns}
            size={this.props.size}
            shop={this.props.shop}
            printingZone={this.props.printingZone}
            picked={this.state.pickedColors}
            previews={this.props.previews}
            product={this.props.product}
            setDone={this.productCreated}
            baseProduct={this.getBaseProd()}
            displaySuccess={this.props.displaySuccess}
            generatorError={this.displayError}
            status='edition'
            setKey={this.setKey}
            products={this.props.products}
            productLoading={this.props.productLoading}
          />
        </GeneratorFlow>
      )
    }
    return (
      <GeneratorFlow>
        <ColorPicker
          picked={this.state.pickedColors}
          toggleColor={this.toggleColor}
          baseProduct={this.props.baseProduct}
          toggleFirstColor={this.setFirstColor}
          variation={this.props.variation}
          selectAll={this.toggleAll}
          setVariation={this.props.setVariation}
          selectedColor={
            this.props.variation ? this.props.variation.value : null
          }
          setPreviewColor={this.props.setVariation}
        />
        <FullDesignSelector
          designs={this.props.designs}
          select={this.props.select}
          addedDesigns={this.props.addedDesigns}
          getImage={this.props.getImage}
          printingZone={this.props.printingZone}
          removeDesign={this.props.removeDesign}
          active
          setStep={this.setStep}
          showBP={this.showBP}
          showDS={this.props.showDS}
          setKey={this.setKey}
        />
        <BaseProductPreview
          addedDesigns={this.props.addedDesigns}
          baseProduct={this.props.baseProduct}
          generatorError={this.displayError}
          size={this.props.size}
          displaySuccess={this.props.displaySuccess}
          shop={this.props.shop}
          picked={this.state.pickedColors}
          setDone={this.productCreated}
          printingZone={this.props.printingZone}
          previews={this.props.previews}
          setPreview={this.props.setPreview}
          status='creation'
          setStep={this.setStep}
          products={this.props.products}
          productLoading={this.props.productLoading}
        />
      </GeneratorFlow>
    )
  }
}
```

And here is the only part thst uses this prop in the child

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import toPx from 'unit-to-px'
import _ from 'lodash'
import { LocalForm, Control } from 'react-redux-form'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { toast } from 'react-toastify'
import { Input, Select, Icon, Tooltip } from 'antd'
import s3 from '../../../../../services/s3'
import theme from '../../../../../theme/theme'
import Alert from '../../../../../components/Alert'
import { createProduct, modifyProduct } from '../../../../../modules/products'

// import ProductImage from '../../../../../components/ProductImage'


class BaseProductPreview extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    let colors
    if (props.product) {
      colors = Object.assign([], props.product.variations.filter(v => v.type === 'color'))
    } else {
      colors = []
    }
    this.state = {
      name: props.product ? props.product.name : '',
      displayDescription: props.product ? Object.assign({}, props.product.displayDescription) : {},
      collections: (props.product && props.product.collections) ? props.product.collections : [],
      pricing: props.product ? Object.assign({}, props.product.pricing) : { margin: 0 },
      elevdone: false,
      i: 0,

      colors,
    }
    this.createInnerProduct = this.createInnerProduct.bind(this)
    this.getPrice = this.getPrice.bind(this)
  }

  oneColor() {
    if (this.props.baseProduct.variations && this.state.colors) {
      let colorAlert
      if (this.state.colorAlertShown) {
        colorAlert = <Alert message='Choisissez au moins une couleur' type='error' />
      }
      const colorsBp = this.props.baseProduct.variations.filter(v => v.type === 'color')
      if (colorsBp.length <= 1) {
        return ''
      }
      return (
        <div>
          <p>Choix de couleur :</p>
          { colorAlert }
          <span
            className='bullet-color'
          >
            {this.getColorsRef(this.props.baseProduct).map(value =>
              (<div
                onClick={() => { this.toggleColor(value) }}
                className={this.colorIsInProduct(value)}
                style={{ backgroundColor: value }}
              />))}
          </span>
        </div>)
    }
    return null
  }


  getColorsRef() {
    return this.props.baseProduct.variations.filter(v => v.type === 'color').map(a => a.value)
  }

  colorIsInProduct(couleur) {
    // true/false
    let active
    if (this.state.colors.find(v => v.value === couleur)) {
      active = 'active-color'
    }
    return active
  }
  toggleColor(couleur) {
    // const item = this.state.item
    const colors = this.state.colors
    // si on a deja la couleur dans le produit on l'enlève
    if (colors.find(v => v.value === couleur) && colors.length > 1) {
      // je retire cette couleur des varaitions de mon produits
      const index = colors.indexOf(colors.find(v => v.value === couleur))
      colors.splice(index, 1)
    } else if (colors.find(v => v.value === couleur)) {
      this.setState({ colorAlertShown: true })
    } else {
      // on va chercher la variation couleur corespondante
      // dans le base product et on la copie dans le product
      this.setState({ colorAlertShown: false })
      colors.push(this.props.baseProduct.variations.find(v => v.value === couleur))
    }
    this.setState({ colors })
    // TODO on change la couleur du mockup
  }

  getJsonsObjects(printingZones) {
    // INITIATE EMPTY JSON OBJECT
    const jsonsArray = {}

    // GET CURRENT CANVAS

    printingZones.map((item) => {
      const y = document.getElementById(`${item}-canvas`).fabric
      const helper = _.filter(y.getObjects(), { clipFor: 'layer' })[0]
      if (helper) {
        helper.set({ stroke: 'transparent' })
      }
      jsonsArray[item] = y.toJSON(['height'])
    })
    return jsonsArray
  }



  getCustomizationPrice() {
    let customizationPrice = 0
    Object.keys(this.props.baseProduct.printingZone).map((item) => {
      const y = document.getElementById(`${item}-canvas`).fabric
      const items = y.getObjects()
      if (items.length > 1) {
        customizationPrice = customizationPrice + 5
      }
    })
    customizationPrice = customizationPrice - 5
    if (customizationPrice < 0) {
      customizationPrice = 0
    }
    return customizationPrice
  }

  getAction() {
    return (<p>Créer mon produit</p>)
  }

  marginValidation(value) {
    let returned_value = value
    if (value == '') {
      returned_value = 0
    }
    if (!value) {
      returned_value = 0
    } else if (value > 100) {
      // TODO Show moreThan100Alert
      returned_value = 100
    }
    const pricing = Object.assign({}, this.state.pricing, { margin: returned_value })

    this.setState({ pricing })
  }
  validForm() {
    if (this.state.name && this.props.picked.length > 0 && this.state.pricing.margin >= 0 && this.props.addedDesigns.length > 0) {
      return false
    }
    return true
  }
  getPrice() {
    const position_print = this.props.addedDesigns.map(d => {
      return d.position
    })
    // uniq(position_print)
    const count = []
    position_print.map((position) => {
      if (count.indexOf(position) === -1) {
        count.push(position)
      }
    })
    if (count.length <= 1) {
      return (
        <div>
          <p className='price'>Cout de production <span>{this.props.baseProduct.unitPrice} €</span></p>
          <div className='price-marge'>Vos bénéfices <span className='requiredField2'>*</span>
            <Control.text
              component={Input}
              className='inputMarge'
              model='.margin'
              value={this.state.pricing.margin}
              onChange={(e) => {
                this.marginValidation(e.target.value.replace(',', '.'))
              }}
            />
          </div>
          <hr />
          <div className='price-total'>
            {`
        ${parseFloat(this.props.baseProduct.unitPrice)
        +
        parseFloat(this.state.pricing.margin)} €`}
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
    if (count.length > 1) {
      return (
        <div>
          <p className='price'>Cout de production <span>{this.props.baseProduct.unitPrice} €</span></p>
          <p className='price'>Impression supplémentaire <span>5 €</span></p>
          <div className='price-marge'>Vos bénéfices <span className='requiredField2'>*</span>
            <Control.text
              component={Input}
              className='inputMarge'
              model='.margin'
              value={this.state.pricing.margin}
              onChange={(e) => {
                this.marginValidation(e.target.value.replace(',', '.'))
              }}
            />
          </div>
          <hr />
          <div className='price-total'>
            {`
          ${parseFloat(this.props.baseProduct.unitPrice)
          +
          parseFloat(this.state.pricing.margin) + parseFloat(5)} €`}
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
    return null
  }

  getCategory() {
    if (this.props.baseProduct.category.fr[0] === 'Homme' && this.props.baseProduct.category.fr[1] === 'Femme') {
      return (<span>Unisex</span>)
    }
    if (this.props.baseProduct.category.fr[0] === 'Homme') {
      return (<span>Homme</span>)
    }
    if (this.props.baseProduct.category.fr[0] === 'Femme') {
      return (<span>Femme</span>)
    }
    return null
  }
  showElevio() {
    if (this.state.i < 5) {
      this.state.i = this.state.i + 1
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.props.productLoading.loading === true || this.props.products.length === 0) {
          if (this.props.products.length === 0 && this.state.elevdone === false) {
            return (
              window._elev.openArticle(263),
              this.setState({ elevdone: true })
            )
          } return null
        }
        if (this.props.productLoading.loading === false) {
          this.showElevio()
        }
        return null
      }, 500)
    } return null
  }
  render() {
    const { Option } = Select
    const children = []
    if (this.props.shop.settings.collections) {
      this.props.shop.settings.collections.map((collec, i) => {
        children.push(<Option key={collec.name ? collec.name : i}>{collec.name}</Option>)
        return null
      })
    }
    this.showElevio()
    return (
      <StyledBaseProductPreview>
        <h2>Description</h2>
        <LocalForm
          onSubmit={() => this.createInnerProduct()}
        >
          <div className='form-step'>
            <p className='advice-name'>
              <Tooltip title='Figurera sur la fiche produit'>
                <span>{this.props.baseProduct.subCategory.fr} {this.getCategory()}</span>
              </Tooltip>
            </p>
            <p>Nom <span className='requiredField'>*</span></p>
            <Control.text
              component={Input}
              model='.name'
              placeholder='Nom du produit'
              value={this.state.name}
              onChange={(e) => {
                this.setState({ name: e.target.value })
              }}
            />
          </div>
          <div className='form-step'>
            <p>Description</p>
            <Control.textarea
              className='productDescription'
              model='.displayDescription'
              placeholder='Description du produit'
              value={this.state.displayDescription.fr}
              onChange={(e) => {
                const new_item = Object.assign({}, this.state.displayDescription)
                new_item.fr = e.target.value
                this.setState({ displayDescription: new_item })
              }}
            />
          </div>

          <div className='form-step'>
            <p>Collection(s)</p>
            <Select
              mode='multiple'
              className='styledSelect'
              placeholder='Pas de collection'
              notFoundContent='Pas de collection'
              value={this.state.collections}
              style={{ width: '100%' }}
              onSearch={(e) => {
                this.setState({ toCreate: e })
              }}
              onChange={(e) => {
                this.setState({ collections: e })
              }}
            >
              {children}
            </Select>
          </div>
          <div className='form-step pricingForm'>
            <h2>Prix </h2>
            <hr />
            {this.getPrice()}
          </div>
          <Crumpet type='submit' className='superCrumpet' disabled={this.validForm()}>
            {this.getAction()}
          </Crumpet>
        </LocalForm>
      </StyledBaseProductPreview>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  console.log(state); // state
  console.log(ownProps); // undefined
  return({
    user: state.user,
    addedDesigns: ownProps.addedDesigns,
  })
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({
  createProduct,
  modifyProduct,
}, dispatch)

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(BaseProductPreview)
```

When inspecting these elements, I can see the parent getting updated :

[image: Parent props]

And now, the funny part: when parent props get updated, the first two child component props are updated as well, but BaseProductPreview doesn't !

[image: Child props]

However, this gets updated as soon as I change the state of the child component.

How comes so ? How can the state update the component props ?

Comment: Can you show your Parent and Child

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I updated the question to display the components

Comment: When and where is getPrice being called from

Comment: Did you bind your function with your instance of the object? You can do this using the following line when you call your function: `getPrice().bind(this)`

Comment: Are you sure in ProductGeneratorFlow  component you are getting new props for addedDesigns and from which components you have added the images?

Comment: I tried all of these, still failed :(. The strangest part is, I got 3 child components, which receive the exact same props, and whenever the parent component props are updated, two of the children get updated, but the last one doesn't

Comment: What is your parent component?

Comment: I added it to  the question. is there any chance this comes from BaseProductPreview being connected to redux ?

Answer (score 0):

React only act on state not on props. whenever you change state UI gets update with latest changes. bind your props to state in child component and use componentWillReceiveProps(props) to change child state when props get updated in parent component.

Comment: you can use componentwillreceiveprops if you want to update state if props changes. Child components gets updated props even without having this lifecycle method

Comment: yes, correct but you can not change props in child component. you must change you state in grand parent so that it will reflect in child and in between updated props you want perform any operation you can use componentwillreceiveprops to operate on props. hope so it will clear point.

Comment: Agreed. we cant change props anywhere. in order to update props, main parent from where the props are sent should handle it

Comment: @Pierre Olivier Tran follow that pattern to  change state  in parent . it will automatically get update in child component

Comment: @javed I tried, for some reason it updates other child components, but not this one (see question update). I think it is becuase this child component is redux-connected, although i'm not sure why

Comment: @PierreOlivierTran plz add all component code (grand parent to child) in your question. then i will suggest.

Comment: @PierreOlivierTran you code looking good. I think issue with redux updation, check FullDesignSelector  component in that are you dispatching any action  to update addedDesigns.

Answer (score 0):

Well the only solution I found was to connect a higher component with redux, so that none of the children were redux-related anymore, and then pass the reducer function through props to that child.

Without redux, my component gets updated properly.